# lvm mirroring space unavailable

Tags: lvm

I am trying to migrate my data on lvm to two new disks, and setup mirroring between the two.  I have successfully migrated all of the data to the first of the two disks, leaving the second one completely available as a mirror.  I verified this using `pvdisplay -m /dev/sd{g,h}1`

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdg1
  VG Name               vg
  PV Size               931.51 GiB / not usable 3.19 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              238466
  Free PE               82866
  Allocated PE          155600
  PV UUID               v2nc3j-EFBR-QpuG-xgro-Rm59-fmu6-IB3QcR

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 49999:
    Logical volume  /dev/vg/videos
    Logical extents 0 to 49999
  Physical extent 50000 to 99999:
    Logical volume  /dev/vg/home
    Logical extents 0 to 49999
  Physical extent 100000 to 129999:
    Logical volume  /dev/vg/music
    Logical extents 0 to 29999
  Physical extent 130000 to 155599:
    Logical volume  /dev/vg/videos
    Logical extents 50000 to 75599
  Physical extent 155600 to 238465:
    FREE

  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sdh1
  VG Name               vg
  PV Size               931.51 GiB / not usable 3.19 MiB
  Allocatable           yes 
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              238466
  Free PE               238466
  Allocated PE          0
  PV UUID               LuTrem-WcsZ-qw7l-2CDS-lLKI-wdq0-QEXhLf

  --- Physical Segments ---
  Physical extent 0 to 238465:
    FREE
```

Then when I try to mirror the `home` logical volume for example, it says that I do not have sufficient space.  I used `lvconvert -m1 vg/home` and the output was:

```
  Insufficient suitable allocatable extents for logical volume : 50000 more required
  Unable to allocate extents for mirror(s).
```

This puzzling to me because it appears as if there is plenty of space on the second disk to mirror.  Is there something I have done wrong here?  Or is there a way to explicitly tell LVM where to put each leg of the mirror?  I'm using lvm2.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have enough space for the mirrorlog. The default is having the mirrorlog on a disk (in a separate PV). See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lvm2/+bug/121527 for more info.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but I'm not sure why the other answer links to a bug report. Unfortunately LVM does a really bad job of explaining why it's saying it's out of space, but you can prevent this altogether with adding "--mirrorlog core" to the end of your lvconvert line. This will keep the log in memory instead of writing it to disk.

Big Disclaimer though: This should only be used for a transient (ie disk migration) event, because with the mirrorlog in memory, it will lose the mirror after a reboot. I use this because we have to migrate our SAN devices from one frame to another when they go out of warranty, and I break off the old mirror after the sync is complete. If you want a permanent solution for mirroring, I'd recommend using mdadm, or setting up another volume (I believe it has to be in it's own VG, but I could be wrong) for the mirrorlog. Or you could use hardware RAID if your infrastructure supports it.